# Video stop on div hide

Tags: javascript, video, html, hide

I know this has been addressed before but I don't know enough about code to apply the other solutions to my own problem, since my code is different. My video is not a Youtube video, its just in my web folders.

Basically I have the video popping up in a div on autoplay. When you click of the vid hides, which I want, but the audio keeps playing. I just want the video to stop playing when the div is hidden, and I can't seem to figure out how to plug in the correct code. If someone could help me I'd really appreciate it. Thanks.
This is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
document.onclick=check; 
function check(e){ 
var target = (e && e.target) || (event && event.srcElement); 
var obj = document.getElementById('mydiv'); 
if(target!=obj){obj.style.display='none'} 
} 
</script>


 <div id="mydiv"><video autoplay><source src="socialphobiavideo.mp4"></video></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an [`id`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/global-attributes.html#the-id-attribute) to your [`<video>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-video-element.html#the-video-element) and use [`pause()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/media-elements.html#dom-media-pause) to stop it:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
document.onclick = function check(e){ 
    var target = (e && e.target) || (event && event.srcElement); 
    var obj = document.getElementById('mydiv'); 
    if(target != obj){
        obj.style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('myvideoelement').pause();
    } 
} 
</script>


<div id="mydiv">
    <video id='myvideoelement' autoplay>
        <source src="socialphobiavideo.mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure about javascript, so I don't know where to put the pause() exactly.

Comment: @Sarah: Sorry, I accidentally used `stop()` instead of `pause()`. The code above should work.